# Wordpress menu triangle caret

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, hover

Trying to add a triangle caret to my wordpress menu.
Got the triangle from css triangle generator, and simply added to a:hover styles. 
Two problems are:
 1)it doesn't stay the original size (15px wide and 10px long) and gets li's width, with adjusting height
 2)only part of height is seen. the rest gets hidden under link

```
#btmn ul li a:hover {
font-size: 14px;
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 10px 7.5px 0 7.5px;
border-color: #4f69bf transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

live link here
http://soloveich.com/pr4/

Comment: I think your issue is that you are making the whole link into a triangle instead of revealing a triangle like div above the link.

Comment: I feel like that too, but couldn't manage to make it work on hover in separate div. Any ideas on making it happen?

Comment: Can you post an image about it when you hover what to show .Just post an sketch image

Comment: something like that http://s020.radikal.ru/i716/1401/94/a9a029a08941.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use another element, or you could use a pseudo class like :after - not all browsers will animate an :after --- so that is the main downfall - but it is much more semantic that having a whole other element just for a triangle, some people would argue. Basic understanding of positioning is key. I tried to leave good notes. Good luck! - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/zra5V/)

### html

```
<nav class="special-nav">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

### CSS

```
.menu {
    float: left; /* or not */
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden; /* $shame use a clear fix instead */

    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.02); /* just so you can see */
}

.menu li {
    float: left;
}

.menu a {
    position: relative; /* so you can position things absolutely to its borders */
    display: block; /* to give the shape */
    padding: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a:after {
    content: "\0020"; /* because you need something in this pseudo element for it to work */
    position: absolute; /* to position based on parent */
    top: 0;
    left: 50%; /* to center-ish */
    margin-left: -5px; /* basically half your triangle width  for further centering */

    /* triangle */
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 7.5px 0 7.5px;
    border-color: transparent;

    transition: all .3s linear; /* or not */
}

.menu a:hover:after {
    border-color: #4f69bf transparent transparent transparent;
    transition: all .1s linear;
}
```

Comment: sweet! tnx! Any way to keep it on for current page?

Comment: It depends what you are using. Are you using PHP (WordPress) or anything like that? If so, the current page probably has the class="current" or something like that. You can use that to help you out. It needs to "know" what page it is on - and that either needs to be spit out by a CMS or whatever, or it has to be stored somewhere so it knows.